# Send complex command via ssh

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm trying to send this command via ssh:

```
ssh <user1>@<ip1>  ssh <user2>@<ip2> /opt/user/bin -f /opt/user/slap.conf -l /home/admin/`date +%Y%m%d`_Export_file$nr.gz -s "ou=multi" -a "(& (entry=$nr)(serv=PS))" -o wrap=no
```

this command is customized so do not confuse with this...
But it's not executed, smth like:  unexpected '(

If i log in to the server and i give this command it gets executed correctly. So i think it should be something with bracket and parentheses rules.

Please can someone help me?

thank  you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to escape the quotes, possibly twice, since each invocation of ssh will involve stripping a layer off. Put escaped single quotes round the entire command, and then nested unescaped single quotes round the inner command:

```
ssh <user1>@<ip1>  \'ssh <user2>@<ip2> '/opt/user/bin -f /opt/user/slap.conf -l /home/admin/`date +%Y%m%d`_Export_file$nr.gz -s "ou=multi" -a "(& (entry=$nr)(serv=PS))" -o wrap=no'\'
```

This assumes, by the way, that you want the backticks to be unpacked and the command executed on `ip2`, rather than beforehand on your source machine, and similarly with the decoding of the `$nr` variable. It's not clear how you want them interpreted.

Comment: ssh <user1>@<ip1>  \'ssh <user2>@<ip2> '/opt/user/bin -f /opt/user/slap.conf -l /home/admin/`date +%Y%m%d`_Export_file$nr.gz -s "ou=multi" -a "(& (entry=$nr)(serv=PS))" -o wrap=no'\'
>
>
it gets executed in the background i think...